# Inverse modulo function

Tags: functions, inverse

How can we calculate the inverse of a modulo function, now I have a problem given me $f(n)=(18n+18)\mod29$, need find inverse of $f(n)$ ? how is the process to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check that $\gcd(18,29)=1$. As $29$ is prime, this is obvious.
Hence this is a bijection.

---

Using our friend [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+18++modulo+29) you solve the equation:
$$
18y + 18 = x \mod 29
\\
y+1 = 21x \mod 29
\\
y = 21x+28\mod 29
$$
and you find:
$$
f^{-1}(x) = 21x+28
$$

Comment: if change the question to (18n+17)mod29, then the result should be 21(x-17)mod29 ? i think 18n+18 is a more special sample here.

Comment: @atom2ueki: exactly.

Answer (score 0):

$\gcd(29,18)=1,\,$ so $\ {\rm mod}\ 29\!:\  \color{#c00}{18^{-1}}$ exists, so $\ m\equiv 18(n\!+\!1)\iff n\equiv \color{#c00}{18^{-1}} m - 1,\ $ and

$$ {\rm mod}\ 29\!:\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{1}{18}}  \,\equiv\, \dfrac{30}3\dfrac{30}6 \,\equiv\, 10\cdot 5\,\equiv\, 21\equiv -8$$